# Class of the language of Turing machines that loop on at least one input

Tags: regular-languages, turing-machines, turing-completeness

$L = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid \text{there is at least one input string on which the \(M\) does not halt} \}$

Here, for a Turing machine $M$, the notation $\langle M \rangle$ denotes an encoding, over some alphabet, of the code of the Turing machine. To which of the following language classes does $L$ belong?

1. Regular.
2. Context-free but not Regular.
3. Recursive but not Context-free.
4. Recursively enumerable but not recursive.
5. Not recursively enumerable.

Comment: since it is given that M doesn't halt(i'm stuck here)
if it is just that M "halts on some input x",then it is easy to say that it is regular,non-recusive..but it is given that M doesn't halt.

Comment: You're missing the point. The language is not the one accepted by $M$, but rather the one accepted by $L$. The question is, how hard is it to tell whether a given Turing machine halts on all inputs?

Answer (score 1):

The language $L$ consists of (descriptions of) Turing machines $M$ such that $M$ does *not* halt on all inputs. In other words, $\langle M \rangle \notin L$ if $M$ halts on all inputs. Can you think of any connection to the halting problem?

Comment: i don't think any connection to halting problem

Comment: can u please elabroate ur answer i didn't get it!!

Comment: This is not an answer, but rather a hint. You will have to take it from here on your own.

Comment: for ur inteligency..._/\ _....

Comment: @user561298 The language is defined in terms of whether Turing machines halt or not.  Are you sure there's no connection with the halting problem?